# Impossible to send response after headers have being sent

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

Currently I'm developing an Express app using middlewares. First step, I need to authenticate the users. In `app.js` I've:

```
app.post('/api/ecosystem/project/auth',
    middleware.authenticate,
    function(req,res){
    }
);
```

In the middleware, I need to access to the params provided by the user, so I access to `body`, setting headers. In `middleware/index.js`:

```
function authenticate(req, res, next){
        var plainPassword = req.body.password,
            userName = req.body.username;

        models.connection.query(
               `SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE username = ?`,
               [userName] ,function(err, query) {
                     var err = true; //for testing purposes
                     if (err) res.statusCode = 500;

               console.log('continues');
               //...
```

The problem comes when I try to send the status code turning back. As headers have been set, I can't use res.send(), res.status(), next() with an error param and so on. If I do that, I have an error about `Headers have already been sent`. There's a [very amazing answer here about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent).

So I can use just `res.statusCode` but this does not return the status and does not stop the flow. Also, I can't send other params as `err.message` in a JSON file.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store statusCode in `err` object and pass it to `next` function. If your routes are defined properly, you should have middleware for handling unprocessed errors. That handler can use `err.statusCode` to set correct response statusCode.

```
function authenticate(req, res, next){
  var plainPassword = req.body.password;
  var userName = req.body.username;

  models.connection.query(
    `SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE username = ?`,
    [userName],
    function(err, query) {
      if (err) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
        return next(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

In your `routes.js` you must have:

```
YOUR ROUTES

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err);
});
```